# How to make the frequency table based on the multiple columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I guess it could be a duplicated question, but I could not find the solution.
I want to make a frequency table in python.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'group': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
    'category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c' ]
})
df
# sample    group   category
#0     A        X          a
#1     A        X          b
#2     B        Y          a
#3     C        Y          b
#4     B        Z          c
#5     C        Z          a
#6     C        Z          c
```

And this is an expected result that is similar to the frequency table.

```py
# sample    group   a   b   c
#0     A       X    1   1   0
#1     B       Y    1   0   0
#2     C       Y    0   1   0
#3     B       Z    0   0   1
#4     C       Z    1   0   1
```

I tried using `crosstab`, `groupby`, and `pivot_table` functions, but all of them failed to get the correct result.

```py
pd.crosstab(df.sample, df.category) #is it available with only two variables?
```

```py
df.groupby(['sample', 'group']).category.value_counts(normalize=False)
#I think that this is similar to my expected result, but I want the form like an adjacency matrix
#sample  group  category
#A       X      a           1
#               b           1
#B       Y      a           1
#        Z      c           1
#C       Y      b           1
#        Z      a           1
#               c           1
#Name: category, dtype: int64
```

```py
pd.pivot_table(df['sample'], df['group'], df['category'], aggfunc=','.join)
```

How can I make the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because exist function [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) is better use `[]` like dot notation, for multiple columns use list:

```
df = pd.crosstab([df['sample'],df['group']], df['category'])
print (df)
category      a  b  c
sample group         
A      X      1  1  0
B      Y      1  0  0
       Z      0  0  1
C      Y      0  1  0
       Z      1  0  1
```

---

```
df = pd.crosstab([df.sample, df.group], df.category)
print (df)
category                                                  a  b  c
row_0                                              group         
<bound method NDFrame.sample of   sample group ... X      1  1  0
                                                   Y      1  1  0
                                                   Z      1  0  2
```